# Android - java.lang.NullPointerException when getting JSON

Tags: android, json, rest

I'm facing this error when getting JSON from the server I'm using RestClient. I really can't figure out why. When I use the same source code in doInBackground method it works but when I used it otherwise I didn't work ! I tested the url in the browser and it retuns JSON. I really appreciate your help and thanks in advance.

```
    inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2,int arg3) {

    RestClient rc = new RestClient("url");

        try {
            rc.Execute(RequestMethod.GET);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String reponse = rc.getResponse(); // this return null that's why I have java.lang.NullPointerException but I don't know why ? It don't get informations from the server     

     final Container container = gson.fromJson(reponse,Container.class);
    }
...
```

This is my RestClient class:

```
public class RestClient {

    private static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT = 5000;
    private static final int SOCKET_TIMEOUT = 5000;
    private static final long MCC_TIMEOUT = 5000;

    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> params;
    private ArrayList <NameValuePair> headers;

    private String url;

    private int responseCode;
    private String message;

    private String response;

    public String getResponse() {
        return response;
    }

    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public int getResponseCode() {
        return responseCode;
    }

    public RestClient(String url)
    {
        this.url = url;
        params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        headers = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    }

    public void AddParam(String name, String value)
    {
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void AddHeader(String name, String value)
    {
        headers.add(new BasicNameValuePair(name, value));
    }

    public void Execute(RequestMethod method) throws Exception
    {
        switch(method) {
            case GET:
            {
                //add parameters
                String combinedParams = "";
                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    combinedParams += "?";
                    for(NameValuePair p : params)
                    {
                        String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),"UTF-8");
                        if(combinedParams.length() > 1)
                        {
                            combinedParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            combinedParams += paramString;
                        }
                    }
                }

                HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url + combinedParams);
                setTimeouts(request.getParams());

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }

                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
            case POST:
            {
                HttpPost request = new HttpPost(url);
                setTimeouts(request.getParams());

                //add headers
                for(NameValuePair h : headers)
                {
                    request.addHeader(h.getName(), h.getValue());
                }

                if(!params.isEmpty()){
                    request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, HTTP.UTF_8));
                }

                executeRequest(request, url);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    private void executeRequest(HttpUriRequest request, String url)
    {
        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpResponse httpResponse;

        try {
            httpResponse = client.execute(request);
            responseCode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            message = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();

            HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {

                InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
                response = convertStreamToString(instream);

                // Closing the input stream will trigger connection release
                instream.close();
            }

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e)  {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            client.getConnectionManager().shutdown();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static void setTimeouts(HttpParams params) {
        params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, SOCKET_TIMEOUT);
        params.setLongParameter(ConnManagerPNames.TIMEOUT, MCC_TIMEOUT);
    }
}
```

And this is my RequestMethod

```
public enum RequestMethod {
    GET, POST
}
```

this is my logcat :

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Activity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-17 20:46:13.472: E/AndroidRuntime(2027): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
... 11 more
```

Comment: Post stacktrace for exception

Comment: You probably have an exception during `rc.Execute` and because `rc.getResponse()` is not in the `try` statement you get a null response.

Comment: Can you post your full logcat, without editing ?

Comment: I reupdated my question

Comment: I found an error: the code `String paramString = p.getName() + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(p.getValue(),"UTF-8");
                        if(combinedParams.length() > 1)
                        {
                            combinedParams  +=  "&" + paramString;
                        }`
make you have something like this: `http://theurl.tld?&param1=val1&param2=val2`. You should add the **&** only from the second parameter. Anyway, this doesn't explain the NullPointerException.

Comment: It's going to drive me crazy, the same code source works in doInBackground method with the same url, why It doesn't work like that It should return JSON but It doesn't get at all JSON from the server

Comment: Well the problem is: what is the line that causes the NullPointerException?

Comment: response = rc.getResponse() returns null, it's not getting JSON from the server that means that rc.Execute is not executing